# DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn: FormatException on boolean-column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, formatting

I have not even an idea where to look to fix this error.
Recently i get following exception after i've clicked the checkbox in   a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` to check it  and leave that cell:

> System.FormatException: "" is not valid for Boolean

Here's the complete error dialog from the `DataGridView`:

[image]

I even don't know which event i could handle to find the reason for this issue. The `Validating` and the `CellFormatting` events are triggered before the error, but both run through.
If i handle the `DataError`-event i still  can't figure it out. The `DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs` argument contains following informations(among others):

```
e.ColumnIndex = 0 
e.RowIndex    = 0 
e.Context     = Commit
```

The full exception(`e.Exception.ToString()`) is:

> System.FormatException:  is not a valid value for Boolean. --->
>   System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean. 
>   at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.BooleanConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ComponentModel.BooleanConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(Object value)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.PushValue(Int32
>   boundColumnIndex, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Object value)

Here's a screenshot of the relevant column properties, the column has `ThreeState=false` and nothing specified for `FalseValue`, `TrueValue` or `IndeterminateValue`:

[image]

The datasource of the `BindingSource` is a `List<ErpService.ArrivalChargeAssignment>` where `ArrivalChargeAssignment` is a class from my WCF webservice with a `bool`-field `IsAssigned`, so it can never be `null` (or even an empty string).

Comment: I remember getting an error like this (though not quite the same message) when our team was working on a legacy project. It turned out there was some sort of race condition going on-the data source was being changed/read in multiple different threads and the control didn't like it. We spent a lot of time on it but couldn't figure out what was causing it (locks didn't help either). We eventually ditched WinForms and moved on to WPF. Probably not the answer you were looking for, but if it's a brand new project it will be worth it to write it in WPF.

Comment: I was also getting this same error whenever DGV tries to format the value in specified datatype format. i couldn't solve this issue. So, I have handled the `DataError` event to avoid this exception.

Comment: @Nimesh: Yes, maybe i'll also swallow this exception although i don't like to ignore exceptions all the more if i don't know the reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I have done some testing with windows form designer and I found something strange in code generator. So, What i have done in my testing is

First I have added a column with `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` type and populated the `datagridview` with a data table. I have add some record with null values.

Now, it was working fine and data showing correctly and also it was not giving any error.
Then I have changed the `DefaultCellStyle` property of that `CheckedBoxColumn` and removed `False` value from `Nullvalue` property and start it again. 
Now, application is showing that error.

I came back to that `DefaultCellStyle` property and set the `False` value back. then I have run that project again. But, still it was showing me the same error.

So, loaded the `Form.designer.cs` file and checked the `dataGridViewCellStyle1` object. where I have found that the property is set with the string type value `"False"` instead of boolean type `false`.

```
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.NullValue = "False";
this.Column1.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
this.Column1.HeaderText = "Check Box";
this.Column1.Name = "chkCol";
```

So, I have updated that line as follows and started the project again. Now, the error is gone.

```
dataGridViewCellStyle1.NullValue = false;
```

When I have created that `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` I found that there is no object is created for default cell style property. So, by default `NullValue` property was taking `false` value. but, after modifying that property the object has been created and the property is assigned with string type value.

**UPDATED:** This issue can be resolved by simply re-creating that column.

Comment: Thank you very much. Strange that i have not tried to recreate the column which should be the first action with MS products(reboot) ;) Thanks again.

Comment: Nice Answer, Precisely written

Comment: welcome @TimSchmelter, always happy in helping and I have also learned something new today.

Comment: Hey I had the same problem 3 years ago and still found the same answer :)  Maybe I'll remember next time.  It is even funnier if the solution is your own post!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do one thing. While creating your grid, you can assign the boolean "true" or false ( as shown below ). In the above question, the column index is 0 and the rowindex can be accessed as you create the grid. You will not get the error. I faced the same problem and resolved it as shown below. Appreciate the other 2 answers also.

```
DataGridViewCell oCell;
oCell = dataGridView["Your Column Index", "Your Row index"];
oCell.Value = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with the same problem and have a simple fix without having to write any code.

The problem is not with the "TrueValue" or "FalseValue" parameters, and you don't need to trap the error handler. The problem in a nutshell is when the DataGridView object adds a new row (hence the error fires during the initial paint), but the root of the problem is that the data in the new row has not yet been initialized, hence it is "indeterminate"....so just set a default value for the "IndeterminateValue" instead of leaving it empty.

Answer (score 0):

use this may be use full

```
private void DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView1["Your Column Index", e.RowIndex].Value = Convert.ToBoolean(DataGridView1["Your Column Index", e.RowIndex].Value);
        }

private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(DataGridView1["Your Column Index", e.RowIndex].Value))
            {
                DataGridView1["Your Column Index", e.RowIndex].Value = false;
            }
            else
            {
                DataGridView1["Your Column Index", e.RowIndex].Value = true ;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved it in a elegant way, if your database column type is boolean ("**bit**") and your DataGridView **AutoGenerateColumns** is true, then a **DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn** will be generated, so all you need to do is change the default true and false values and the data type.

Generic code to **resolve the issue**, insert after DataSource assingment:

```
foreach ( DataGridViewColumn dc in DataGridView1.Columns)
{
    if (dc.ValueType == typeof(Boolean))
    {
        dc.ValueType = typeof(Int32);
        ((DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)dc).DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = 0;
        ((DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)dc).TrueValue = 1;
        ((DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)dc).FalseValue = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the previous answers, but was still getting repeatable DataErrors.

I was getting a "myColumnName Not Found in myDataTable" error preceding the format exception error in my DataGridView.DataError events.  I resolved it reliably (I think) by clearing and resetting the DataGridView's BindingSource any time before I reassign the BindingSource.DataSource.  For example:

```
void ReloadMyData()
{
    myBindingSource.DataSource = null;
    myBindingSource.ResetBindings(true);
    DataTable myDataTable = CreateOrReloadMyDataTable();

    // If I do not do the BindingSource clear and reset above,
    //   the following DataSource reassignment throws the DataError exceptions.
    myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
    myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource;
}
```

My Development Platform: Visual Studio 2019, 16.8.4, C# .NET 4.6.2 WindowsForms, Windows 10 LTSC